# Unable to cast object of type 'Data' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im getting this error "Unable to cast object of type 'Data' to type 'System.IConvertible'."
in my code

```
foreach (Data p in clusters[i])
 {
   for(int z=0; z<53;z++)
    {
      if (values[z] = Convert.ToInt32(p))
      {
         lray[z].BackColor = colorSet[i];
      }
    }
  }
```

"values" is an integer array and p is from Data class

```
class Data
    {

        public int X, ClusterId;
        public Data(int x)
        {
            this.X = x;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("({0})", X);
        }
        public static int DistanceSquared(Data p1, Data p2)
        {
            int diffX = p2.X - p1.X;
            return diffX * diffX;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is the condition in `if` statement `values[z] = Convert.ToInt32(p)` typo? should be comparison operator `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intent is not clear from your code.

`p` in an object of `Data`. Seems you want to access the data you have saved in the member X of p

But you could do it like this

```
foreach (Data p in clusters[i])
 {
   for(int z=0; z<53;z++)
    {
      if (values[z] == p.X)
      {
         lray[z].BackColor = colorSet[i];
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply what the error says. You have to implement IConvertible in your Data class for this to be used like this.

[IConvertible Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Youe `Data` class clearly does not implement `System.IConvertible`. So you can either do so or perform some other check in your if.

```
class Data : System.IConvertible
{// implement necessary methods of System.IConvertible here 
}
```

Side note: `=` is assignment, you likely meant `if (values[z] == ...)`